# Антиалайзинг на iOS openGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl, opengles

Как включить антиалиайзинг линий (openGL ES 2.0) в iOS?

Англоязычная публика не очень помогла, оригинальный вопрос здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832734/is-there-a-way-to-use-multisampling-with-glkview-in-ios

**UPD:**
Использую GLKView

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ответ исчерпывающий, только не помог. Т.к. `setDrawableMultisample: GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X` не работает, а даёт черный экран.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте во время инициализации GLKView вызвать это для включения msaa во вьюхе с вашим GLKView инстансом:

```
[view setDrawableMultisample: GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X];
```

А вообще, обычно делается так:

```
GLint backingWidth,
      backingHeight;

//буферы вьюхи
GLuint viewRenderbuffer,
       viewFramebuffer;

//Msaa буферы
GLuint msaaFramebuffer,
       msaaRenderBuffer,
       msaaDepthBuffer;

// создание буферов
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

//биндинг буефров
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);


// создание мсаа буферов
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &msaaFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &msaaRenderBuffer);

//бинд мсаа буферов
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, msaaFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaRenderBuffer);

// Generate the msaaDepthBuffer.
// формирование мсаа х4
glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_RGB5_A1_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaRenderBuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &msaaDepthBuffer); 

//бинд буфера
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaDepthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth , backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaDepthBuffer);
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ! `glkView.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;` - эта штука не работает, выдает черный экран.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что использование второго подхода лишает возможности использовать GLKView, это правда?

Comment: Во 2 случае вы работаете с помощью OpenGL напрямую с графической подсистемой, без всяких лишних прослоек, что позволяет вам добиться лучшей производительности и лучшего понимания того, что происходит, хотя и кода написать вам придется больше. В целом инфы для OpenGL гораздо больше, если вы там делаете что то не совсем простое в плане графики, то лучше прибегнуть к OpenGL, как  минимум по тому, что коммьюнити большое, и вам будет проще найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Но у меня уже слишком много завязано на glkView, боюсь, что если антиалайзинг так и не заработает посредством этой строчки, придется вокруг линий добавлять прозрачные градиенты, как тут: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/drawing-antialiased-lines/. Но хотелось бы все-таки разобраться, почему мультисэмплинг не включается. Тестирую на iPhone 5s, вроде бы все должно работать. (когда великий stackoverflow разрешит - сделаю upvote, ещё раз спасибо!)